# connect to local, public mysql server

Tags: java, mysql

Ok, long story short. I have a local mysql server setup atm via wamp. I have it set to online. When I run my program via eclipse, and JDBC set to localhot, it works just fine, but if I set it to use my external IP, it won't connect. I have checked the ports, and scanned them as well, they come back as mysql server listening on port 3306. I think I ran into a problem like this several years ago, something about it being a loopback issue, how can I get around this? At the very least, how can I be sure that the db is public and running ok if I can't force my local system to connect with the external IP?

Comment: Has your user got login permission from outside localhost? MySQL authentication is host specific.

Comment: what is the output of `SELECT DISTINCT GRANTEE FROM information_schema.USER_PRIVILEGES WHERE GRANTEE LIKE '\'yourusername%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do telnet on your public server ip port.

```
telnet yourpublicserverip sqlport
```

If it succeeds then your ip-port combination is available from outside. If it does not then most likely it will be a firewall issue and you may have to open your firewall to allow incoming connections on your sqlport.